# Java class to objective-C class

Tags: java, objective-c, cocoa, methods, code-conversion

i need to know what is the equivalent code for the code below in Objective-C

```
public MyClass(int x, int y) {
        xCoOrdinate = x;
        yCoOrdinate = y;
    }

    public int getXCoOrdinate() {
        return xCoOrdinate;
    }

    public int getYCoOrdinate() {
        return yCoOrdinate;
    }
    public MyClass func() {
        return new MyClass(xCoOrdinate - 1, yCoOrdinate);
    }
```

**this is what i tried :**

```
    -(id)initWithX:(int )X andY:(int)Y
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        self.xCoOrdinate = X;
        self.yCoOrdinate = Y;

    }
    return self;
}
-(MyClass *)func
{

    return [self initWithX:(self.xCoOrdinate -1)  andY:self.yCoOrdinate];
}
```

is this a right way ?

Comment: Are you compiling with or without ARC, and is this code targeting iOS or OS X?

Comment: @jlehr compiling without ARC and targeting iOS

Answer (score 4):

No. You need to return a new instance of the class:

```
-(MyClass *)func
{
    return [[[[self class] alloc] initWithX:(self.xCoOrdinate - 1)  andY:self.yCoOrdinate] autorelease];
}
```

Notice we use `[[self class alloc]` to create a new instance of the current class, `MyClass`.

Comment: The new instance should be autoreleased because, according to Cocoa's memory management conventions, a method named "func" would not return an owned object.

Answer (score 1):

A few corrections :

```
public int getXCoOrdinate() {
    return xCoOrdinate;
}
```

would become :

```
- (int)getXCoOrdinate
{
    return [self xCoOrdinate];
}
```

**and**

```
public MyClass func() {
    return new MyClass(xCoOrdinate - 1, yCoOrdinate);
}
```

would become :

```
+ (MyClass*)func
{
     MyClass* newFunc = [[MyClass alloc] initWithX:0 Y:0];

     if (newFunc)
     {
     }
     return newFunc;
}
```

Comment: The getter is unnecessary, he creates the variables as properties, as shown by his syntax.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I just tried to explain HOW it should be done in a general fashion. Of course, if he uses `@property` no getters/setters may be needed...

Comment: The convention in Objective-C is not to prefix getters with "get".  You should just call it `xCoordinate`

Comment: @JeremyP Good point. I know, of course. Though I tried NOT to confuse the OP (I just decided to stick to his way of naming the functions).